# Koa-passport - "Internal error: illegal access" when accessing the req parameter

Tags: node.js, passport.js, koa, koa-passport

Hi all I am messing with Koa and Koa passport and experiencing an issue when working with Koa passport and variants on the LocalStrategy.  First I tried to option into the LocalStrategy the passing of the req to the authentication method (your function is stored in their  _.verify variable). A snippet of the code in **LocalStrategy**:

```
if (self._passReqToCallback) {
  this._verify(req, username, password, verified);
} else {
  this._verify(username, password, verified);
}
```

No go - the app just hangs (which doesn't happen if you don't option that method in). So then I decided to mess with my own strategy to see where things are off.  Ultimately I started looking at **passport/middleware/authenticate.js** where the authenticate function returns a contained authenticate function, where there is a self invoked attempt function.

Here (well at least here) looks to be the issue.  An **attempt to access the req variable** gives the **"Internal error: illegal access"** message.  However  access to the res and next parameters from the same signature return appropriate values - "object" and "function".

I am a bit lost here, and while I could work around this, I would rather not.

---

Update 1

koa-passport/lib/framework/koa.js there is a req object that is "mocked" out of the koa context, via Proxy, which might be the cause of the "illegal access" message.  Accessing req.path works fine at this point/file...